# How do I fix XYZ Math Surface error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"?

Tags: add-on, error, mathematics

I am trying to create an object using the *Add > Mesh > Math Function > XYZ Math Surface* option from the [Add Mesh Extra Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html) add-on. However, when I input my equation `f(b, v)`, I get the warning "Error evaluating expression(s) - Check the console for more info". Opening the console, I see the following error:

```
[Add X, Y, Z Function Surface]:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\scripts\addons\add_mesh_extra_objects\add_mesh_3d_function_surface.py", line 320, in xyz_function_surface_faces
    safe_dict['f'] = float(eval(*expr_args_f))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

My troublesome equation is `f = v*arccos(1-(48+32*sqrt(2))/(4*b**2+4*sqrt(2)+7)**2)`. It references the (error-free) parameter `b = 1/2*(sqrt(2)+1)*(2*u-1)/(sqrt((2*u-1)**2+1)+1)`.

What part of my equation is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Searching for the error message online has not been helpful, as it seems to be a generic error that is triggered when a function returns "None" instead of a usable value, but that doesn't explain how to find and fix the issue.

How to get to the XYZ Math Surface option:
[image: Image showing how to get to the XYZ Math Surface option]

The default configuration of a new XYZ Math Surface mesh:
[image: Image showing default settings for a new XYZ Math Surface mesh]

Adding my function for `b` causes no problems:
[image: Image showing equation for the "b" variable added]

But adding my function for `f` throws an error:
[image: Image showing equation for the "f" variable added, with the error window open]

The console window with the error message:
[image: Image of the System Console window]

Comment: @Chris What do you mean by "a fully runnable code example"? I am not writing code, I am using Blender's normal interface. I am only entering two equations into said interface before getting the error message, the equation for `b` (which works fine) and the equation for `f` (which triggers the error).

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your question

Comment: try using acos instead or arccos

Comment: @Chris That fixed it! Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome